# MC 1.9: Chunk Loader for Redstone Circuits?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have developed an automatic train system using minecarts and redstone circuits to let the minecarts travel between stations. It worked so far for lines in the near environment. But I noticed that it fails for longer distances, because the chunks are not loaded - therefore the minecart will stop and never come back, until the chunks were loaded by a passing player.

[image: Train System Sketch]

I am using a 1.9 Vanilla server, and I have full access to the server.

The Chunks don't need to be loaded when no player is on the server. But if there are players, the chunks containing the stations and the line should always be loaded when players are online.

How can I achieve this?

I am willing to install server mods, if necessary, but I only found a mod for MC 1.7. For some tutorials, I am confused about "Lazy Load chunks" and "entity chunks", and I do not know which type I need for my scenario. I also read that it might be possible using command block chains, but I do not know exactly how this works (and if it actually works for this scenario).

---

I do not understand why you think it is a duplicate. Once again, if the end station is set to a spawn point, then the whole track in the middle (the powered rail) won't work. So the linked question doesn't fit the problem situation.

Comment: On the topic of duplicates, the judgement is done by practicly random people. They are one with rather high reputation, but sometime they may make rushed judgements. You have stated why you think the marked duplicate doesn't answer your question. (It wouldn't hurt to make this even clearer.) Now it's up to the _reopen_ queue to make the judgement.

Comment: @Daniel-Marschall I would write an answer, but...well, the thing is that only constantly loaded chunks are spawn chunks, but you can extend this to also other chunks....force load others with activity from already loaded ones. Look at this video to see how you can do it: https://youtu.be/egqsmXD_oCM

Comment: The hopper chunk loader is probably one of the only solutions to your problem of unloaded Chunks.

Comment: The distance is 1000 blocks. Spawn chunks have to be within 128 blocks of the spawn. This clearly can't be solved with spawn chunks. Reopening.

Comment: I have done the hopper chunk loader concept, and I also made a 2 chunks wide border around that tracks (the youtube video says this allows entities to work.) a redstone clock 1000 blocks away will work, but mine carts don't come back. Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: @Daniel Marshall I edited my answer in hopes it may answer your question.

Comment: To answer my question: The original hopper-chunk-loader did work, but there was a small mistake I did: At one end-station, a track was "scraping" at a chunk-border. Therefore the track was accidently placed in a lazy-chunk, so the train stopped and never came back. I have moved the track a few blocks to the inner of the chunk, and now it works. The train(s) now fully automatically travel from station A to B with a distance of 1000 blocks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is put them in your Spawn Chunks.  Spawn Chunks are a 16×16 area of land that is stored in the memory therefore never unloads the Chunks.

Here redstone and commands should work as long as there is a player in the overworld.  Meaning that they won't work if what you have is In the  Neather or the End and no player is in the overworld.

No mods are needed for this to work and there are tutorials on how to find your Spawn Chunks.

You can also increase your spawn chunks using the hopper chunk loader:

You can find the edges of each chunk by hitting `F3`[image]

If you look under Block you will see Chunk.  The first number after the `in` will tell you what chunk your in.  Play with the other two to find the edge.

Edit:  This video explains tbe last video as well as introduces a new concept that may work better.

Comment: But the problem is, that not only the redstone circuits of the endstation(**s**) has to be always loaded, but also the whole line, otherwise the minecart will be stuck in middle of nowhere, even if both end stations are loaded and functional.

Comment: Chunk loaders have been asked for before and I believe there are some, but they may not work in 1.9.  Many there is an alternative method to your problem other than chunk loaders.

Comment: I do not understand why you think it is a duplicate. Once again, if the end station is set to a spawn point, then the whole track in the middle (the powered rail) won't work. So the linked question doesn't fit the problem situation.

Comment: @ire_and_curses No problem, I did notice this,but as commented by Antoine Hejlík there are ways to increase the spawn chunk limit with the hopper chunk loader so I didn't need to include it in my answer.

Comment: Will do. Work for the +1

Comment: It's pretty involved, but if that pseudo-chunk loader works in modern MC, then this is a great answer to the problem. +1 :)

Comment: I have finally solved the problem using the hopper-method described in the video. It was hard work to enclose the whole track and the end stations, but now it works fine :-)

Answer (score -1):

press f3 and A at the same time, it will recode all chunks.if this does not work press fn, then press f3 and a at the same time.

Comment: But that is not an automatic solution.

Comment: F3 and A reloads the chunks in the client, it can't force more chunks to be loaded by the server